# Forms ValidationError and error code

Tags: django, django-forms

In Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror said that it is good practice to prodive error code while raising ValidationError exception.

```
# Good
ValidationError(_('Invalid value'), code='invalid')

# Bad
ValidationError(_('Invalid value'))
```

I have API in my application and I'm using form to validate input data.
If form is not valid, I whant to get these error codes (not error messages).

So I looked at source code of _clean_fields method of BaseForm:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L278

```
except ValidationError as e:
    self._errors[name] = self.error_class(e.messages)
    if name in self.cleaned_data:
        del self.cleaned_data[name]
```

As I understand this parameter (`self.code`) is not passed anywhere and can not be obtained after the form validation.

Can someone explain what the purpose of using this error code?

Comment: Seems like that's a new addition - see the note that says "new in 1.6", which isn't even released yet - so probably it's not fully implemented everywhere.

Comment: This field also present in 1.5. Looks like you're right and it's something to be used in a future release.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Django 1.7, you can now access the original error data from the form. You can call the `as_data()` method on an `ErrorList` or `ErrorDict`. For example: `my_form.errors.as_data()`. This basically gives you the original `ValidationError` object instead of the message itself. From this you can access the `.code` property, eg: `my_form.errors["__all__"].as_data()[0].code`.

You can also serialize form errors, great for APIs:

```
>>> print(form.errors.as_json())
{"__all__": [
    {"message": "Your account has not been activated.", "code": "inactive"}
]}
```

Comment: As of django 1.10 the right way to access the code would be form.errors.as_data()['field_name'][0].code

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ValidationError definition in django src, it's used as a convenient way to pass additional identifier (similar to `e.errno` in standard python exception), you can use it like this:

```
try:
    ...
    raise ValidationError(u'Oops', code=0x800)
    ...

except ValidationError as e:
    print "Error code: ", e.code
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I want to keep the value of this code after form validation I need to rewrite _clean_fileds method?

Comment: that or see Daniel's comment above, they probably still working on that, so it's better to just wait, so you won't have incompatibilities when upgrading.